# Oracle Sql Select Query Error in Where Condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Suppose, I have a query with a where condition that is false. In this case nothing will be printed. But I want to print something if where condition is false.

How to achieve this?

If where condition is true:

```
Select ename from emp where empno = '1234';

output
===========
ename   
======   
Jagdish
```

If where condition is false:

```
select ename from emp where empno = '545120';

output
================
ename
=================
```

When where condition is false I want to display "no data found" or anything like 'N/A'. Can you please help with that

Answer (score 2):

If you are always expecting at most one row, you can use aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(ename), 'N/A')
from emp
where empno = '1234';
```

An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns one row.  If all rows are filtered out, then the aggregation functions return `null` -- hence, the `coalesce()` to get what you want.

Note:  This assumes that `ename` is never `null` in the data.

Comment: if where condition is false then it is showing null only... But i want to display n/a

Comment: @Jagadish . . . This query, as written, *cannot* return a `null` value.  It could return an empty string, if the name is actually an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with UNION ALL and NOT EXISTS:

```
select ename from emp where empno = ?
union all
select 'no data found' from dual 
where not exists (select 1 from emp where empno = ?);
```

Replace `?` in both queries with the value that you search.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=15cb73d7da61a11d32c160f98140203c).

Comment: It is showing proper when where condition is false but if where condition is true then it is showing two rows ....... So, can i use union for this instead of union all.

Comment: Where did you see 2 rows?

Comment: Did you use the same empno in both queries? I guess you did not.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Check the demo again. Did you copy the code as it is?

Comment: yes when i use union then this is giving proper data which i want

Comment: *when i use union then this is giving proper data which i want* then what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do an OUTER JOIN with DUAL so that a row is always returned:

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.ENAME, 'No data found') AS ENAME
  FROM DUAL d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP e
    ON e.EMPNO = '545120';
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add a `CASE` statement in your select clause as:

```
select CASE WHEN ename IS NULL THEN  'N/A'
       ELSE ename END as ename
from emp where empno = '545120';
```

Comment: The query does not return null when there is no empno = '545120'. It returns no rows.

Comment: This query is not display the correct result as per my requirement